# Access DataGrid.RowStyle in AttachedProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lines}}"                      
          uiwpf:DataGridExtensions.CanExportToExcel="True">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

**AttachedProperty:**

```
private static void CanExportToExcelChanged(
    DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Just my way of secure casting DependencyObject -> DataGrid
    if(d is DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        Debug.Assert(dataGrid.RowStyle != null, "Why is this null?");
    }
}
```

**Problem**: Assert is getting triggered - WHY ?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the order in which the properties are being set? So `CanExportToExcel` is being set before `RowStyle`.

Comment: @canton7 that's a good hint. Never thought about that! I will check that !

Comment: You'll probably need to use `CanExportToExcelChanged` to set a binding on `RowStyle` (and remove the binding when `CanExportToExcel` is set to `false`).

Comment: @canton7 I've just confirmed your thought! It seems to be the order. Changing the value of the attached property on runtime shows it clearly is the order. if u feel like posting that as an answer i will accept it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the order in which the properties are being set on the `DataGrid`.

In general (I don't know of any exceptions, but I don't want to claim there *aren't* any) properties are set in the order that they're defined in XAML. So your `DataGridExtensions.CanExportToExcel` will be set to `True` before `DataGrid.RowStyle` is set.

You can test this by removing your current call to `uiwpf:DataGridExtensions.CanExportToExcel="True"`, and putting:

```
<uiwpf:DataGridExtensions.CanExportToExcel>True</uiwpf:DataGridExtensions.CanExportToExcel>
```

**After** you set `<DataGrid.RowStyle>`.

To make your attached property robust, you will probably need to use `CanExportToExcelChanged` to set a binding on the `RowStyle` property (and remove it again when `CanExportToExcel` is set to `False`).